# Minecraft clients' not working

Tags: minecraft

If I start the official Minecraft via the launcher, it works normally.
But whenever I start a different client like Optifine or Forge (Both applications that install *different* Minecraft clients from the official) it crashes. Also, I tried opening log output, but it's usually empty. Occasionally it will output that it crashes with exit code 1 if that means anything.
Sorry if I'm not the greatest question asker.